# Copy array value to another array with HTML button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I have a table of  object that is created from an array on javascript, and I need that the button of each line copy the line to another array.

I've tried to create an empty array and a function that would be called onclick of the button to get the line from the array but didn't worked.

```js
var livres = [
{ref:'b0124',  auteur: 'B.Y.',  titre: 'Connectique',            prix : 5.20},
{ref:'b0254',  auteur: 'L.Ch.', titre: 'Programmation C',        prix : 4.75},
{ref: 'b0334',  auteur: 'L.Ch.', titre: 'JavaScript',             prix : 6.40},
{ref: 'b0250', auteur: 'D.A.',  titre: 'Mathématiques',          prix : 6.10},
{ref:  'b0604' , auteur: 'V.V.',  titre: 'Objets',                 prix : 4.95},
{ref:  'b0025' , auteur: 'D.M.',  titre: 'Electricité',            prix : 7.15},
{ref:  'b0099' , auteur: 'D.M.',  titre: 'Phénomènes Périodiques', prix : 6.95},
{ref:  'b0023'  ,auteur: 'V.MN.', titre: 'Programmation Java',     prix : 5.75},
{ref:   'b0100' , auteur: 'D.Y.',  titre: 'Bases de Données',       prix : 6.35},
{ref:   'b0147' , auteur: 'V.V.',  titre: 'Traitement de Signal',   prix : 4.85},
{ref:   'b0004' , auteur: 'B.W.',  titre: 'Sécurité',               prix : 5.55},
{ref:   'b0074' , auteur: 'B.Y.',  titre: 'Electronique digitale',  prix : 4.35},
{ref:    'b0257' ,auteur: 'D.Y.',  titre: 'Programmation Multimedia', prix : 6.00}
]

  function afficherCatalogue(livres){ // afficher le catalogue
  var ligne;
var ligne2;

    for(var i in livres) {  // pour chaque ligne du catalogue
      ligne = '<tr>';
      ligne += '<td class=ref>' + livres[i].ref + '</td>';  // reference
      ligne += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  // auteur
      ligne += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>';  // titre
      ligne += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  // prix
      ligne += '<td class=ach>' + '<button type="button" onclick="add(i)">acheter</button>' + '</td>';  // futur bouton d'achat
      ligne += '</tr>';
function add(i){
    ligne2 = '<tr>';
    ligne2 += '<td class=ref>' + livres[i].ref + '</td>';  // reference
    ligne2 += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  // auteur
    ligne2 += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>';  // titre
    ligne2 += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  // prix
    ligne2 += '</tr>';
}

            document.getElementById('tbc').innerHTML += ligne;
        document.getElementById('tba').innerHTML += ligne2;
    }
  }
```

```html
<body id=tbc></tbody> //first table already created

<tbody id=tba><!-- table that get the line from the first table --></tbody>
```

Comment: so the function add should create a second table copying the line of the button of the first table

Answer (score 0):

Your code (at least the copy you have here) is very scrambled.

What would work though is move the line:

```
document.getElementById('tba').innerHTML += ligne2;
```

inside the `add` function, like so:

```
function add(i){
    ligne2 = '<tr>';
    ligne2 += '<td class=ref>' + livres[i].ref + '</td>';  // reference
    ligne2 += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  // auteur
    ligne2 += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>';  // titre
    ligne2 += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  // prix
    ligne2 += '</tr>';
    document.getElementById('tba').innerHTML += ligne2;
}
```

Hope to see your library system online soon.

**Edit:**
Here's the whole code after unscramble:

```
var livres = [
    {ref: 'b0124', auteur: 'B.Y.', titre: 'Connectique', prix: 5.20},
    {ref: 'b0254', auteur: 'L.Ch.', titre: 'Programmation C', prix: 4.75},
    {ref: 'b0334', auteur: 'L.Ch.', titre: 'JavaScript', prix: 6.40},
    {ref: 'b0250', auteur: 'D.A.', titre: 'Mathématiques', prix: 6.10},
    {ref: 'b0604', auteur: 'V.V.', titre: 'Objets', prix: 4.95},
    {ref: 'b0025', auteur: 'D.M.', titre: 'Electricité', prix: 7.15},
    {ref: 'b0099', auteur: 'D.M.', titre: 'Phénomènes Périodiques', prix: 6.95},
    {ref: 'b0023', auteur: 'V.MN.', titre: 'Programmation Java', prix: 5.75},
    {ref: 'b0100', auteur: 'D.Y.', titre: 'Bases de Données', prix: 6.35},
    {ref: 'b0147', auteur: 'V.V.', titre: 'Traitement de Signal', prix: 4.85},
    {ref: 'b0004', auteur: 'B.W.', titre: 'Sécurité', prix: 5.55},
    {ref: 'b0074', auteur: 'B.Y.', titre: 'Electronique digitale', prix: 4.35},
    {ref: 'b0257', auteur: 'D.Y.', titre: 'Programmation Multimedia', prix: 6.00}
];

function afficherCatalogue(livres) { // afficher le catalogue
    var ligne;

    for(var i in livres) {  // pour chaque ligne du catalogue
        ligne = '<tr>';
        ligne += '<td class=ref>' + livres[i].ref + '</td>';  // reference
        ligne += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  // auteur
        ligne += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>';  // titre
        ligne += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  // prix
        ligne += '<td class=ach><button type="button" onclick="addLivre(' + i + ')">acheter</button></td>';  // futur bouton d'achat
        ligne += '</tr>';

        document.getElementById('tbc').innerHTML += ligne;
    }
}

function addLivre(i) {
    var ligne2;

    ligne2 = '<tr>';
    ligne2 += '<td class=ref>' + livres[i].ref + '</td>';  // reference
    ligne2 += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  // auteur
    ligne2 += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>';  // titre
    ligne2 += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  // prix
    ligne2 += '</tr>';

    document.getElementById('tba').innerHTML += ligne2;
}
```

Comment: thatks, but it says that there is an error: Uncaught ReferenceError: addLivre is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

Comment: Did you rename add to addLivre as I did? The devil is in the details.

Comment: Just realized it won't work... let me fix your string. `addLivre(i)` should be `addLivre(' + i + ')`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help. On your foreach loop you overwriting your value

```js
var livres = [
    {ref:'b0124',  auteur: 'B.Y.',  titre: 'Connectique',            prix : 5.20},
    {ref:'b0254',  auteur: 'L.Ch.', titre: 'Programmation C',        prix : 4.75},
    {ref: 'b0334',  auteur: 'L.Ch.', titre: 'JavaScript',             prix : 6.40},
    {ref: 'b0250', auteur: 'D.A.',  titre: 'Mathématiques',          prix : 6.10},
    {ref:  'b0604' , auteur: 'V.V.',  titre: 'Objets',                 prix : 4.95},
    {ref:  'b0025' , auteur: 'D.M.',  titre: 'Electricité',            prix : 7.15},
    {ref:  'b0099' , auteur: 'D.M.',  titre: 'Phénomènes Périodiques', prix : 6.95},
    {ref:  'b0023'  ,auteur: 'V.MN.', titre: 'Programmation Java',     prix : 5.75},
    {ref:   'b0100' , auteur: 'D.Y.',  titre: 'Bases de Données',       prix : 6.35},
    {ref:   'b0147' , auteur: 'V.V.',  titre: 'Traitement de Signal',   prix : 4.85},
    {ref:   'b0004' , auteur: 'B.W.',  titre: 'Sécurité',               prix : 5.55},
    {ref:   'b0074' , auteur: 'B.Y.',  titre: 'Electronique digitale',  prix : 4.35},
    {ref:    'b0257' ,auteur: 'D.Y.',  titre: 'Programmation Multimedia', prix : 6.00}
    ]
afficherCatalogue(livres);

    function afficherCatalogue(livres){ // afficher le catalogue
    var ligne;
    var ligne2;

        for(var i in livres) {  // pour chaque ligne du catalogue
            ligne += '<tr>';
            ligne += '<td class=ref>' + livres[i].ref + '</td>';  // reference
            ligne += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  // auteur
            ligne += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>';  // titre
            ligne += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  // prix
            ligne += '<td class=ach>' + '<button type="button" onclick="add(i)">acheter</button>' + '</td>';  // futur bouton d'achat
            ligne += '</tr>';
    
            ligne2 += '<tr>';
            ligne2 += '<td class=ref>' + livres[i].ref + '</td>';  // reference
            ligne2 += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  // auteur
            ligne2 += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>';  // titre
            ligne2 += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  // prix
            ligne2 += '</tr>';
    

                
        }
    document.getElementById('tbc').innerHTML = ligne;
    document.getElementById('tba').innerHTML = ligne2;
    }
```

```html
    <table id="tbc"></table>
    <table id="tba"></table>
```

Comment: Now you only add the last line to the table twice and click sends an undefined value to the also undefined add function...

Answer (score 0):

you can add id to each row and get the location of button click in your add() function. you can store that data from add() function

```
var constlivres = [
        { ref: 'b0124', auteur: 'B.Y.', titre: 'Connectique', prix: 5.20 },
        { ref: 'b0254', auteur: 'L.Ch.', titre: 'Programmation C', prix: 4.75 },
        { ref: 'b0334', auteur: 'L.Ch.', titre: 'JavaScript', prix: 6.40 },
        { ref: 'b0250', auteur: 'D.A.', titre: 'Mathématiques', prix: 6.10 },
        { ref: 'b0604', auteur: 'V.V.', titre: 'Objets', prix: 4.95 },
        { ref: 'b0025', auteur: 'D.M.', titre: 'Electricité', prix: 7.15 },
        { ref: 'b0099', auteur: 'D.M.', titre: 'Phénomènes Périodiques', prix: 6.95 },
        { ref: 'b0023', auteur: 'V.MN.', titre: 'Programmation Java', prix: 5.75 },
        { ref: 'b0100', auteur: 'D.Y.', titre: 'Bases de Données', prix: 6.35 },
        { ref: 'b0147', auteur: 'V.V.', titre: 'Traitement de Signal', prix: 4.85 },
        { ref: 'b0004', auteur: 'B.W.', titre: 'Sécurité', prix: 5.55 },
        { ref: 'b0074', auteur: 'B.Y.', titre: 'Electronique digitale', prix: 4.35 },
        { ref: 'b0257', auteur: 'D.Y.', titre: 'Programmation Multimedia', prix: 6.00 }
    ]

    function afficherCatalogue(livres) { // afficher le catalogue
        var ligne;
        var ligne2;

        for (var i = 0, l = livres.length; i < l; i++) {  // pour chaque ligne du catalogue
            ligne = '<tr id="row-'+ i +'">';
            ligne += '<td class=ref>' + livres[i].ref + '</td>';  // reference
            ligne += '<td class=aut>' + livres[i].auteur + '</td>';  // auteur
            ligne += '<td class=tit>' + livres[i].titre + '</td>';  // titre
            ligne += '<td class=prx>' + livres[i].prix + '</td>';  // prix
            ligne += '<td class=ach><button type="button" onclick="add('+ i +')">copy</button></td>';  // futur bouton d'achat
            ligne += '</tr>';

            document.getElementById('tbc').innerHTML += ligne;
        }
    }

    function add(location){
        console.log('location ---> ', location, document.getElementById('row-' + location));
    }
    afficherCatalogue(constlivres);
```